# Hover images effect issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, mousehover

Hello all and Happy New Year!
I have succesfully added in my css the following image hover effect.
I understand that this is applying in all images on my site. In fact it does :-)
However some images , when hovering are getting outside their place/position. Somewhere I read that I have to include my images in a div. But how can I do that with my all images and where should I put that code?
My site is in joomla 3.3
I tried to put the div code in index.php but with no luck.
Please excuse me for my ignorance. I learn fast though :-)

EDIT: I would like to be more specific. I would like to have the hover effect in a joomla module. It displays news articles with images. I noticed this code in the module.

```
<div class="image">
<img src="<?php echo $items[$i]->image;?>" alt="<?php echo $items[$i]->title;?>">
</div>
```

So I think that images are included in a div. Am I right with that?
And I replaced in the first css the "img" with "image". And I added after that the overflow:hidden
That's what I have right now, but images are still getting out from their place.

```
.image{
    -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 800 ease; /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: all 800ms ease; /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transition: all 800ms ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 800ms ease;
}
.image:hover{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.20); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.20); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.20); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.20); /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.20);
}
.image{overflow:hidden;}
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: More code would be helpful.

Comment: do you *want* all images to scale? Or is that a mistake?

Comment: @KyleT the problem is that images are getting outside their place when I hover them, as I said. I can't describe it better, sorry. My english are poor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw now your edits (sorry, for the late answer). I will respond here because i can't in the main question. What you need to do is add another class to the div that contains the image, for example new_effect. Then, in the css file, add new rules for that class, and it should be ok. For example:

HTML:

```
<div class="image new_effect"> <!--this div has 2 classes-->
  <img src="<?php echo $items[$i]->image;?>" alt="<?php echo $items[$i]->title;?>">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.new_effect{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.new_effect img{
  -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 800 ease; /* Firefox */
  -o-transition: all 800ms ease; /* IE 9 */
  -ms-transition: all 800ms ease; /* Opera */
  transition: all 800ms ease;
}
.new_effect img:hover{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.20); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform:scale(1.20); /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform:scale(1.20); /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform:scale(1.20); /* Opera */
   transform:scale(1.20);
}
```

You shouldn't need any jquery script.. as always, ask for further info

Answer (score 0):

If you put the image inside a div like this example:

css:

```
div{
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 450px;
}
```

html:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.libertyscentre.co.uk/Owls/large/Collared%20Scops%20Owl.jpg" width="300">
</div>
```

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/myh8qz2s/

the element will occupy the same position.

***IMPORTANT EDIT***

If the images are too many and you don't want to wrap all the images, you can just use this simple jquery script:

```
$(function(){
   $("img").each(function(){  //runs trough all the images
     height = $(this).height();  //get height of the current image
     width = $(this).width();    //get width of the current image


     $(this).wrap('<div class="container" style="width:'+width+'px; height:'+height+'px;"></div>');  //wraps the current image in a div of same height and width *check also the css for the class container

    });

});
```

NEW FIDDLE: (css is the same as before)

http://jsfiddle.net/myh8qz2s/1/

Feel free to ask

Comment: This is excactly what I would like to do. But I don't know where to put the html code and jquery code. Should I put them in index.php?

Comment: If you want to wrap manually every image by yourself, go in the page where there are the images to be wrapped in the container and put the div (with a class decleared in css) around the image.

If you want to use the script, put the code that i wrote inside a <script> tag, inside the <head> tag.

Note that the script will get ALL the images (<img>). If you want to be more specific change the following line:


    $("img").each(function(){

Into something more specific, for example a class:

    $('.class_of_the_image').each(function(){

Comment: I am back with results! Unfortunatelly it seems that there is a conflict with jquery as I understand... I put the script inside the head, I edit my css file and that worked but some other images disappeared. With your script as you have it , I had no luck. I replaced the $ with "jquery" and I have some luck....I must be wrong somewhere....but where?

Comment: Please edit your question and put some of the new code edited by you, so everyone can see and help you again!

Comment: I just did. I hope I didn't do any mistake...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `transform-origin: center` property. This is shown in the first image - [see more](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Within the second image, I have wrapped the image in a div with a class called 'container'. this container has a set height and width, and I have given it `overflow:hidden` property. This means that the image will 'enlarge', but will not 'be seen' outside of this container.

```css
img {
  -webkit-transition: all 800ms ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 800 ease; /* Firefox */
  -o-transition: all 800ms ease; /* IE 9 */
  -ms-transition: all 800ms ease; /* Opera */
  transition: all 800ms ease;
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.20); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform: scale(1.20); /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform: scale(1.20); /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform: scale(1.20); /* Opera */
  transform: scale(1.20);
  
  
  -webkit-transform-origin: center;
  -moz-transform-origin: center;
  -o-transform-origin: center;
  transform-origin: center;
}



.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" />




<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Second image is what I would like. But as I said to the other user, I don't know where to put that html code. I use joomla 3.3 so I am thinking to put it in the index.php right?

Comment: I've never used php / joomla before to be honest. How are you inserting your images? I don't suppose you're using the same sized images bac?